# Error when trying to train LSTM model with windowed dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

The following code is how I preprocess my data:

```
WINDOW_SIZE = 8 # Previous 7 days are inputs and the following day (8th) is the expected output 
BATCH_SIZE = 16
SHUFFLE_BUFFER = 10

dataset = Dataset.from_tensor_slices(israel_new)
# Output (167, )

dataset = dataset.window(WINDOW_SIZE, 1, drop_remainder=True)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda x: x.batch(WINDOW_SIZE)) # Used to change the type from Window to Tensor
# Output: (160, 8)

dataset = dataset.shuffle(SHUFFLE_BUFFER)
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: (x[:-1], x[-1]))
# Output (160, 2)

dataset = dataset.batch(32).prefetch(1)

for x, y in dataset:
    print(x.numpy().shape, y.numpy().shape)
# >>> (32, 7) (32,)
# >>> (32, 7) (32,)
# >>> (32, 7) (32,)
# >>> (32, 7) (32,)
# >>> (32, 7) (32,)
```

And this is my model:

```
inputs = Input((None, 7))
x = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(inputs)
x = LSTM(64)(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
model.compile('adam', 'mse', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(dataset, epochs=5)
```

when I try to fit my model I am getting this error: `Input 0 of layer lstm_43 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, None]`

why is this happening?

Comment: Why would you have `Input((None, 7))` instead of the actual dimensions?

Comment: @mabergerx Do you mean why I use the Input object? it's the same as specifying input_shape, it's just easier for me to read.

Comment: No, I mean why do you put the explicit `None` in there, instead of following the `Input(shape=(32, 7))` kind of syntax?

Comment: @mabergerx I am a beginner but as far as I know, you don't specify the batch size in the input shape, it's inferred by Keras in the background, I tried both `(32, 7)` and just `(7)` but both don't work, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
inputs = Input(7)
x = keras.layers.Reshape((7, 1))(inputs)
```

The model previously received an input of `(None, 7)` which does not correspond with the shape of the dataset `(32, 7)` because an LSTM layer needs an extra 1 dimension at the end `(32, 7, 1)` and we don't specify the batch size when giving an input shape, so we just reshaping the inputs from `(32, 7)` to `(32, 7, 1)` where the `32` (`batch size`) is handled by Keras in the background.